# react-dom/test-utils, TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I use `react-dom/test-utils` to test my react component.

But the return value of `scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass` has no `props`

and `props.children` property. Did I do something wrong or what?

here is my test code:

```
it('renders item count correctly', () => {
    const $$searchList  = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SearchList items={datas}/>)
    const list = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass($$searchList, 'list');

    expect(list.props.children).toHaveLength(4);
    expect(items).toHaveLength(4);

  });
```

here is the test result:

```
● component - SearchList test suites › renders item count correctly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/List/__tests__/SearchList.test.jsx:17:26)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

  component - SearchList test suites
    ✓ loads without error (43ms)
    ✕ renders item count correctly (18ms)
```

-- update --

Here is my component render:

```
return (
      <div className="list">
        {
          items.map((item: Book, idx: number): React.ReactElement<IListProps<Book>> => {
            return (
              <ListItem onClick={() => this.onItemClick(item, idx)} key={item.id} item={item}/>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass does not allow you to assert props on found components, while scryRenderedComponentsWithType does. More on that can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5852)

Before to React 0.14, scry/find...WithClass would have returned the DOM component. With the release of 0.14, these methods return **the DOM node itself**. In neither of these cases would the props of a composite component be accessible.

You can also decide to use enzyme which has much more simple syntax for shallow rendering and finding your sub-components and their props then the syntax of react test utils (scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass, scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag and scryRenderedComponentsWithType).
You can read why and more [about it here](http://codeheaven.io/testing-react-components-with-enzyme/)